# VBA macro INSTR function in triple if statement

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I try to use the "instring" function to make a triple filter for a counter.
The main idea is to define a range and then check every cell as follows:

1) Locate content "0111" in cell

2) If content "0111" in cell found, check on the column left of this cell, if content "127" exists

3) Check if the row of the current cell is not red (color 3)

4) If all the above is true, raise counter.

My code looks as follows:

```
Set SrchRng4 = Range("J1:J100")

 For Each cel In SrchRng4
   If InStr(1, cel.Value, "0111", 1) > 0 Then
   If InStr(1, ActiveCell(Offset(-1,0), "127", 1) > 0 And  cel.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex <> 3 Then
        count_K = count_K + 1

    End If
Next cel
```

It work for the search of "111" and the exeption of the red rows but it doesn't work after the addition of the "127" filter. 
Can anyone provide some input on that ? I suppose it some problem with the syntax ?

Kind regards,
Marcus

Comment: try with `If InStr(1, cel.Offset(-1,0), "127", 1) > 0 And  ...`

Comment: @KazimierzJawor5 gave you the solution except for `cel.Offset(-1,0)` must be `cel.Offset(0,-1)`. Furthermore, should you have time performance issues, you may want to filter on first two conditions and then loop through filtered cells only to check the last one

Comment: Hallo guys, thank you for the replies. The loop does not seem to close, now the error is at the last row of the code:  "compile error: Next without For"

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each cel In Range("J1:J100")
    If InStr(cel, "0111") And InStr(cel( ,0), "127") _ 
        And cel.EntireRow.Interior.Color <> vbRed Then count_K = count_K + 1
Next
```

- Numeric values that are not 0 are evaluated to `True`, so `> 0` is optional
- `cel(,0)` is similar to `cel.Offset(0,-1)` to get the cell left of `cel`
- `vbRed` and `rgbRed` are constants for the color red, but `.ColorIndex <> 3` is fine too
- each `If .. Then` statement should have a matching `End If` statement, unless it is on one line